# bash optional command in variable

Tags: bash

i have a code:

```
L12(){
echo -e "/tftpboot/log/archive/L12/*/*$sn*L12*.log /tftpboot/log/diag/*$sn*L12*.log"
command="| grep -v hdd"
}
```

```
getlog(){
echo $(ls -ltr $(${1}) 2>/dev/null `${command}` | tail -1)
}
```

however $command does not seem to be inserting `| grep -v hdd` correctly
i need $command to be either empty or `| grep`
is there a simple solution to my issue or should i go for different approach

edit:

there may be another problem in there

i am loading a few "modules"

EVAL.sh

```
ev(){
case "${1}" in
*FAIL*) paint $red "FAIL";;
*PASS*) paint $green "PASS";;
*)echo;;
esac
result=${1}
}
```

rackinfo.sh (the "main script")

```
#! /bin/bash
#set -x
    n=0
    for src in $(ls modules/)
        do
            source modules/$src && ((n++))
## debugging
# source src/$src || ((n++)) || echo "there may be an issue in $src"
    done
## debugging
# x=($n - $(ls | grep src | wc -l))
# echo -e "$x plugin(s) failed to laod correctly"
# echo -e "loaded $n modules"
########################################################################
command=cat
tests=("L12" "AL" "BI" "L12-3")
while read sn
        do
                paint $blue "$sn\t"
                for test in ${tests[@]}
                        do
                                log="$(ev "$(getlog ${test})")"
                                if [[ -z ${log} ]]
                                        then
                                                paint $cyan "${test} "; paint $red "!LOG "
                                else
                                                paint $cyan "${test} ";echo -ne "$log "

                                fi
done
echo
done <$1
```

the results i get are still containing "hdd" for `L12()`

Comment: You need to use `eval`

Comment: Why did you put `${command}` inside backticks?

Comment: Use `| $command` and set `command=cat` when you don't want to filter anything.

Comment: i have tried using `eval`, `| $command` and `command=cat` but unfortunately the `grep -v hdd` does not get processed correctly and i get outputs containing hdd

Comment: `ls -ltr $(${1}) 2>/dev/null | if [[ "$do_grep" == true ]]; then grep -v hdd | tail -1; else tail -1; fi`. Be aware that file lists provided by `ls` can be problematic in scripts.

Comment: @dan i am trying to achive to be as universal as possible in `getlog()` writing the `grep -v hdd` in it would limit me quite some in future i may want to grep a match in `L10()`  and `-v` match something different in `L12-3()`

Comment: @DominikHájek So you have two branches: whether to filter, and which filter. Instead of hard coding, you can use an array as Barmar suggested. Another option with that is `"${command[@]:-cat}"` for `cat` as default. For a more complex filter, eg multiple commands, you can use a function instead of an array, in a similar manner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set `command` to `cat` as a default.

Also, it's best to use an array for commands with arguments, in case any of the arguments is multiple words.

There's rarely a reason to write `echo $(command)`. That's essentially the same as just writing `command`.

```
#default command does nothing
command=(cat) 

L12(){
    echo -e "/tftpboot/log/archive/L12/*/*$sn*L12*.log /tftpboot/log/diag/*$sn*L12*.log"
    command=(grep -v hdd)
}

getlog(){
    ls -ltr $(${1}) 2>/dev/null | "${command[@]}" | tail -1)
}
```